# How do I use SUM function in MySQL to return '0' if no values are found

Tags: sql, sqlcommand

I want my sum function to return '0', if a value does not exist, Can anyone identify if there is a problem with the following SQL command. I have changed the order of the coalesce but this has not made a difference

```
SqlCommand scGetPostings = new SqlCommand(@"
SELECT 
  D1.dr, 
  D1.cr, 
  D1.asset_no, 
  (open_bal + dr - cr) AS closing_balance 
FROM (SELECT 
        COALESCE(SUM(dr_amount), 0) AS dr, 
        COALESCE(SUM(cr_amount), 0) AS cr, 
        asset_no 
      FROM posting, sysasset 
      WHERE posting.asset_no = @AssetNumber 
        AND period >= asset_open_per 
      GROUP BY asset_no) AS D1, asset 
WHERE D1.asset_no = asset.asset_no", DataAccess.AssetConnection);
```

Comment: Code looks like correct. What is the problem? Are you getting `NULL` for `dr` or `cr`?

Comment: Yeah, if there is no value for this, i expect this code to return a '0' but its not returning anything, the code works because it returns records that have values in them.

Comment: Do you want to see value or 0 if there are no records for each `asset_no`?

Comment: Yes thats what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  asset.asset_no, 
  COALESCE(dr, 0) AS dr, 
  COALESCE(cr, 0) AS cr, 
  (open_bal + COALESCE(dr, 0) - COALESCE(cr, 0)) AS closing_balance 
FROM 
    asset LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT 
        SUM(dr_amount) AS dr, 
        SUM(cr_amount) AS cr, 
        asset_no 
      FROM posting, sysasset 
      WHERE posting.asset_no = @AssetNumber 
        AND period >= asset_open_per 
      GROUP BY asset_no) AS D1 
ON D1.asset_no = asset.asset_no
```

Answer (score 0):

use `if condition` in your statement:

```
SqlCommand scGetPostings = new SqlCommand(@"
SELECT 
  D1.dr, 
  D1.cr, 
  D1.asset_no, 
  (open_bal + dr - cr) AS closing_balance 
FROM (SELECT 
        SUM(if(dr_amount is null , 0 , dr_amount )) AS dr, 
        SUM(if(cr_amount is null , 0 , cr_amount )) AS cr, 
        asset_no 
      FROM posting, sysasset 
      WHERE posting.asset_no = @AssetNumber 
        AND period >= asset_open_per 
      GROUP BY asset_no) AS D1, asset 
WHERE D1.asset_no = asset.asset_no", DataAccess.AssetConnection);
```